# How it calculates shape elongation in opencv?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, python-2.7, shapes, feature-extraction

I have many greyscale images since i have to extract features for comparison.
How can i calculate a shape elongation (a basic shape descriptor: http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~mstoj075/Publications_files/elongation-JMIV.pdf) in opencv (better for python version) for feature extraction?

Sample images: 1) https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByS6Z5WRz-h2cE1wTGJwRnE5YUU/edit
2) https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByS6Z5WRz-h2UTFCaVEzaHlXRVk/edit
3) https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByS6Z5WRz-h2NDgySmJ6NnpId0U/edit

Comment: Could you please elaborate? For example include some images, that illustrate your problem? And what exactly do you mean by shape elongation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve elongation feature in python opencv, what kind of moment it supposed to be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854592/retrieve-elongation-feature-in-python-opencv-what-kind-of-moment-it-supposed-to)

Answer (score 1):

Descriptors (shape moments) are created by iterating over a specific shape, and may or may not use the pixel values. The general form you have is this

```
cvFindContours()
Accumulator = 0;
for (each pointx in the contour bounding box)
for (each pointy in the contour bounding box)
{
   if (cvPointPolygonTest((pointx,pointy),mycontour)) //ie the point is not only in the bounding box, but in the actual contour
       Accumulator = Accumulator + MyDescriptor(point,ImageValueAt(point));
}
```

Accumulator will contain your shape descriptor value.
I can't bother reading your pdf but these integrals on the first page translate into your double loop here.

Comment: contour i have was made with contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(imgbnbin, cv2.RETR_TREE ,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) i have to change with CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE? and what is MyDescriptor? a function?

Comment: The chain approximation doesn't matter.
MyDescriptor is the details of the descriptor, if you are for example calculating the area (which is a descriptor), MyDescriptor() will always return 1.

Comment: Just start with calculating simpler descriptors such as area, moment of gravity, etc, and just then go to a complicated one like that in he paper.... it's clear you would need some practice in that.

Comment: it's possible throught moments its calculation: One approach is to calculate the first and second order central moments of the shape described by the 2D contour. Using these values the elongation of the object can be calculated. How?