# Retrieve elongation feature in python opencv, what kind of moment it supposed to be used?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour, feature-extraction

How can i calcalute first and second moment in python opencv and obtaining shape elongation feature?

I'm not so sure about elongation definition, i found: "The less-common elongation shape factor is defined as the square root of the ratio of the two second moments in of the particle around its principal axes"(reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_factor_%28image_analysis_and_microscopy%29#Elongation_shape_factor)

```
f_elong = sqrt (i2/i1)
```

basing on definition, are i2 and i1 spatial moments, central moments or normalized central moments (http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is more than one way to calculate elongation, see the paper "Measuring Elongation from Shape Boundary" for the more standard one as well a proposal of a new one.

Based on this same paper, the standard elongation `E` of a shape `S` is given by:

[image]

where all the moments used are central ones. This feature "is derived from the definition of shape orientation which is based on the axis of the last second moment of inertia. Precisely, the axis of the least second moment of inertia is the line which minimizes the integral of the squares of distances of the points (belonging to the shape) to the line" (taken as is from the paper).

In OpenCV this is directly translated as:

```
import sys
import cv2

def elongation(m):
    x = m['mu20'] + m['mu02']
    y = 4 * m['mu11']**2 + (m['mu20'] - m['mu02'])**2
    return (x + y**0.5) / (x - y**0.5)

img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(sys.argv[1]), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# Assuming input has grayscale dark contours:
img = 255 - cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

m = cv2.moments(img)
print elongation(m)
```

Comment: I just found your approach for computing elongations, but noticed quite some differences to other methods. According to Fig. 1 and 2 of the paper, this is well known. Sometimes the results differ by more than factor 2. :(

Comment: I would check if `(x - y**0.5) == 0` to avoid dividing by zero